# how to calculate all previous datas sum of a sql column on a date range report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with debit credit columns using a sql command. This report contains a date to date filtering parameters. So the problem is if i filter the report to date range i need all the previous data sum using a sql command.

```
Select SUM(CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)))- SUM(CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2)))
from sum_balance 
where sum_date < sum_date
```

this is my code but i can't get the result from it. (e.g. : if the report starting from 2014-07-01 then i need the sum(debit - credit) of all previous data before 2014-07-01). Can anyone help me to find a solution for this. THe main thing is to add a brought forward balance using sql command on first row. If it is null then it should be 0.00.

Comment: `sum_date < sum_date` is always false.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan then to change it

Comment: what `sum_date` consists?

Comment: is there any way to change this @HamletHakobyan

Comment: @Siva  database date column name

Comment: Have you created any parameters in report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your sample table

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(DEBIT NUMERIC(20,2),CREDIT NUMERIC(20,2),DT VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1000 DEBIT,500 CREDIT,'2014-11-27' DT
UNION ALL
SELECT 2000 DEBIT,700 CREDIT,'2014-11-28' DT
UNION ALL
SELECT 3000 DEBIT,900 CREDIT,'2014-11-29' DT
```

I am updating answer for your updated requirement

**QUERY 1**

This will bring the total till current date, ie, for `2014-11-28` the amount will be `(1000+2000)-(500+700)`, for `2014-11-29` the amount will be `(1000+2000+3000)-(500+700+900)`

```
SELECT T2.DEBIT,T2.CREDIT,T2.sum_date,
  (SELECT SUM(DEBIT)-SUM(CREDIT) FROM sum_balance WHERE sum_date <= CAST(T2.sum_date AS DATE))
   AMOUNT
FROM sum_balance T2
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1d89/1)

[image]

**QUERY 2**

This will bring the sum till previous day, that will be opening balance for today's date ie, for `2014-11-29` the amount will be `(1000+2000)-(500+700)`. For easy understanding I have added the previous column also.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(T2.sum_date AS DATE))RNO,
     T2.DEBIT,T2.CREDIT,T2.sum_date,
    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(DEBIT)-SUM(CREDIT) FROM sum_balance WHERE sum_date <= CAST(T2.sum_date AS DATE)),0)
     AMOUNT
    FROM sum_balance T2
)
SELECT C1.*,ISNULL(C2.AMOUNT,0) CARRYFORWARD
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO+1
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b490/1)

[image]

You can use **QUERY 2** and you will get opening balance till previous day in `CARRYFORWARD` column.
Please leave a message or comment for any changes.

Comment: Can't declare a date, because i need the previous sum from the report starting date. e.g if it is 2014-11-29 then i need all of the previous sum before this date, if it will 30th then it will be a different amount, in my report date field name as sum_date is there any way to write a code for this field

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)))- SUM(CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2)))
FROM sum_balance 
WHERE sum_date < (Select Max(sum_date) FROM sum_balance)
```

Comment: nop its not working errror message : Failed to retreive data from database

Answer (score 0):

When you need records previous than `some date` then you need to have that comparision date so that records can be extracted.

Your where clause `where sum_date < sum_date` won't work this way either you change the right side comparision operator in query or create a parameter in crystal so that user can enter the required `end date` during run time.

option 1:

```
E.g: where sum_date < currentdate
```

option 2:

Create a parameter and declare it in `Record Selection Formula` in crystal reports so that formed query will be something like

```
where sum_date < 2014-07-01
```